# How to download file from url using express?

Tags: node.js

I have a image file "https://cdn.my.com/image1.png".

I want to create a proxy to this url from my api.

```
api.get('/download', (req, res) => {

 const url = "https://cdn.my.com/image1.png";

 res.download(url);
});
```

I think `download` is need a file location as argument and not url.

How I can download url as proxy? (**I don't want to wait** to download to complete and send the response after)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `request` the file first and then `pipe` the response to the `res`-object. Something like this:

```
const request = require('superagent')

api.get('/download', (req, res) => {
   res.set(
     'Content-Disposition',
     'attachment; filename=some_file_name.png'
   );

   request("https://cdn.my.com/image1.png").pipe(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const path = require('path');

api.get('/download', (req, res) => {
    res.download(path.join(__dirname, 'image1.png'));
});
```

Let 'image1.png' file and js file to be in same directory